# PHP Force download not working for ZIP file

Tags: php

I am trying to download a zip file using `headers`. But it returns some special character's.

I tried the below code.

```
$filepath='http://localhost/mb/inc/tmp/liberty/xml_invoice.zip'
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.zip');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filepath);
exit();
```

when i run this code i am getting output like some special characters.like below

```
�Q�s�+k�X�ߡB�R�EE����m��@;Ok����A���R�2vZ�j�F�Mo� C�
```

Comment: file path should be the local path, not that this is the actual error here

Comment: Like this `C:\wamp64\www\mb\inc/tmp/liberty/xml_invoice.zip`. Even this also returns same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deliver a ZIP file then you need to use also the correct MIME content type!

```php
$filename = "xml_invoice.zip"
$file = "C:\wamp64\www\mb\inc\tmp\liberty\{$filename}";
header("Content-type: application/zip"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");
header("Content-length: " . filesize($file));
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
readfile($file);
```

Comment: `application/octet-stream` should work as well for forcing downloads.

Comment: What exactly means not working? Do you get the download or an error?
I've tested this script and it works with all test ZIP files!

Answer (score 0):

try this: give path to your zip file.

```
$filepath = "/path/to/some_file.zip";
 $file_name = basename($filepath);
 header("Content-Type: application/zip");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
 header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filepath));
 readfile($filepath);
 exit;
```